How to write the Laplace–Beltrami operator of a function which only depends on the latitude on a radial symmetric hyper-surface.
I want to know how to write the Laplace–Beltrami operator of a radial symmetric function on radial symmetric hyper-surface. For example, a function on a 2-sphere whose value only depends on the latitude.
For example, the Laplace–Beltrami operator on (n-1)-sphere is
$$
\Delta_{S^{n-1}} f(\xi, \phi)=(\sin \phi)^{2-n} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\left((\sin \phi)^{n-2} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}\right)+(\sin \phi)^{-2} \Delta_{\xi} f
$$
where $\Delta_{\xi}$ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator on the ordinary unit $(n-2)$-sphere. In particular, for the ordinary 2-sphere using standard notation for polar coordinates we get:
$$
\Delta_{S^2} f(\theta, \phi)=(\sin \phi)^{-1} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\left(\sin \phi \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}\right)+(\sin \phi)^{-2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2} f.
$$
Then I want the operator to only depend on $\phi$. Here $\phi$ represents the latitude measurement along a unit speed geodesic from the north pole $p$, and $\xi$ a parameter representing the choice of direction of the geodesic in $S^{n-1}$. So for $f$ which only depends on $\phi$, it can be written as
$$\tag{1}
\Delta f=(\sin \phi)^{2-n} \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\left((\sin \phi)^{n-2} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}\right).
$$
Now if I have a random hyper-surface which is radial symmetric about a point p, how can I write the Laplace–Beltrami operator which only depends on the latitude measurement along a unit speed geodesic from the north pole $p$? Is it related to the metric?
For example, the Laplace-Beltrami is
$$\tag{2}
\Delta f=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}} \partial_i\left(\sqrt{|g|} g^{i j} \partial_j f\right).
$$
For the metric on hyper-sphere
$$
g=r^2 d \phi_1 \otimes d \phi_1+r^2 \sum_{a=2}^{n-1}\left(\prod_{m=1}^{a-1} \sin ^2 \phi_m\right) d \phi_a \otimes d \phi_a,
$$
if we set $r=1$ and take $\sqrt{|g|}$ into (2) we will get
$$
\Delta f=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}} \partial_{\phi_1}\left(\sqrt{|g|}  \partial_{\phi_1} f\right)
$$
which coincide with (1), I wonder how could I do the computation for a random hyper-surface which has no spherical coordinate.
